# How to return Promise from an async class function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to unit test a code I re-wrote using promises.
The class FileFactory has the following async function:

```
    async getFileHandler(filePath) {
    var self = this;
    for(const item of self.privateFileHandlers) {
        await item.canHandle(filePath)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log("Response:",JSON.stringify(response));  //line A
            return response;
        }, function(error) {
            return error;
            //ignore since most handlers won't be able to handle.
            //also, the callback after the loop will inform that no filehandler was found.                
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            //console.log('Catching: ',JSON.stringify(err));
            return err;
            //ignore since most handlers won't be able to handle.
            //also, the callback after the loop will inform that no filehandler was found.
        });
    }
}
```

The response I am logging on line A contains what I would expect.

However, in my unit test, I don't get the response object.

```
        it('should return correct FileHandler child instance', function(){  
        var ff = new FileFactory();
        ff.getFileHandler("./tests/H1_20180528.csv").then(function(value) {console.log("Success",JSON.stringify(value));}).catch(function(err) {console.log("Fail",JSON.stringify(err));});
        //ff.getFileHandler("./tests/H1_20180528.csv").then(value => console.log("Success",JSON.stringify(value)));
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(fh));
    });
```

What am I missing here?
Thank you.

This works:

```
async getFileHandler(filePath) {
    var self = this;
    for(const item of self.privateFileHandlers) {
        try {
            let response = await item.canHandle(filePath);
            if(response.status === "success")
                return response;
        } catch(e) {
            //ignore so it does not return on failed canHandle calls.
        }
    }
    throw 'No supporting file handler available.';
}
```

//the updated unit test

```
describe('Select handler', function () {
    it('should fail and return no file handler.', function () {
        var ff = new FileFactory();
        ff.getFileHandler("./tests/H1_20180528_fail2.csv")
        .then(function (value) {
            chai.assert(value.status === null);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            chai.assert(err !== null);
        });
    });

    it('should return correct FileHandler child instance', function () {
        var ff = new FileFactory();
        ff.getFileHandler("./tests/H1_20180528.csv")
        .then(function (value) {
            chai.assert(value.status === 'success');
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            chai.assert(err === null);
        });
    });      
});
```

Comment: The whole point of `async` and `await` is that they allow you to *avoid* explicit Promise wrangling. Code after an `await fn()` is *implicitly* treated as if it were in a `.then()` callback.

Comment: What `value` are you expecting in your test? Your `getFileHandler` doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: Why did you duplicate the error handling code?

Comment: I come from OOP and this is my first dealing with promises in JS. The structure of promise offered both rejected and catch so I filled both. Turns out none of it is needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the inner body of your function to this:

```
try {
   let response = await item.canHandle(filePath);
   console.log("Response:", JSON.stringify(response)); // line A
   return response;
} catch (err) {
   return err;
}
```

If you're `await`ing a function within an `async` function you don't have to use `then` or `catch`.

Comment: It makes no sense to `return` from within a loop though, does it?

Comment: It makes sense. Returning from a loop just breaks out of the loop. What if he wants to iterate over his file handlers, silently ignoring all the ones that error out, and return the first one that succeeds?

Comment: That was my intent.

Comment: @kfedorov91 Yeah, that might have been the intention of the OP, but it hasn't been stated in the question unfortunately.